# Error with Core Data Fetch request 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been having trouble instigating a fetch request over the past few days. Every time I try to launch the view, it crashes with this error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:     'NSFetchRequest could
>   not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'VoiceNotes''"

I use the exact same code (except with a different entity name) on another view, and it works flawlessly. There's nothing wrong with the entity name, it's the same name that the entity has in the data model.

Would someone please be able to help me out?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code for the fetch method:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
if (!self.managedObjectContext) {
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
NSString *entityName = @"VoiceNotes";// Put your entity name here
NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

// Request
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

NSLog(@"test after request");

//request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Role.name = Blah"];

// Sorting
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"toInfo.title"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
// Fetch
NSLog(@"test after request THE SECOND");
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
NSLog(@"test after request THE THIRD");
[self performFetch];
}
```

**Edit:**
I have three entities in my data model, one which is unrelated to this problem, and two which have a relationship running between them. These are called VoiceNotes and VoiceNotesInfo.

Screenshot of the Core Data Model:
[image]

Comment: Could you add some details about your core data model?  It sounds like you don't have an entity called 'VoiceNotes'.

Comment: The problem is though, I do. I'll add some details in a sec.

Comment: This is just an advice, so it does not solve your problem. If you generate (automatically) the `NSManagedObject` subclasses from your model, then you can use as the entity name the result of the macro/function (i don't remember) `NSStringFromClass`, passing the class. This gives you a type checking from the compiler

Comment: @Oliver: If you post a link to a screenshot of the model then we can add it to your question.

Comment: @Martin R : Here's a link: [link](http://imgur.com/T16FSG1)

Comment: Can you show the NSLog output of `[yourManagedObjectModel entities]` ?

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for their help. I managed to work it out. It was a problem with versioning. While I was creating a new version, I inadvertently changed the name of the main data model hierarchy. Therefore, my app delegate had the wrong model name in it. I discovered the real problem after cleaning the build (it came up with the nil model error).
Thanks again!

Comment: Could you answer to your question as soon as possible inserting the comment above. This should be helpful with other people. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, thanks everyone for their help. I managed to work it out. It was a problem with versioning. While I was creating a new version, I inadvertently changed the name of the main data model hierarchy. Therefore, my app delegate had the wrong model name in it. I discovered the real problem after cleaning the build (it came up with the nil model error). Thanks again!

Comment: Thnk you ! I too forgot to update the name of model that I am loading from store